# Nodejs: Search for folders that contain specific words

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a project and want to search and display the list of all the folders that contain the specific words (case insensitive). I only want to search and display the folders and not what's in them nor any other files. How can I do that? I have tried doing so but, couldn't figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
router.get('/displayDirectories', (req, res) => {

    const fs = require("fs");
    const userID = req.query.id;

    fs.access(`C:/Traning/${userID}`, function(err) {
    if(!err)
    {
       console.log("Directory exists");
       //this only prints if I enter the exact full name of the folder
       //I also want to add those directories in an array
    }
    else
    {
       console.log("Directory does not exist");
    }
 })

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question sound not really clear to me (especially if you are looking for one or many files), but regarding to what i understood i hope that could help you

```
const { readdir } = require("fs");
const { join } = require('path')


router.get('/displayDirectories', (req, res) => {

    const userID = req.query.id;
    const thePath = join('C:/Traning', userID)    

    readdir(thePath, (e,d) => {
        if(e) {
            console.log('err parsing the directory: ', e)
            return
        }
        else {
            const list = []

            // set all file's name to lowercase
            const fileLowerCase = d.map(f => f.toLowerCase())
         
            const files = new Set(fileLowerCase)
            // if many files(userIdx) to check: iterate them
            // lowercase the researched file for case insensitive
            if (files.has(userId.toLowerCase()) === true) list.push(userId)
            // another check for ex
            if (files.has(userId2.toLowerCase()) === true) list.push(userId2)
                 
            if(list.length === 0) console.log('directories does not exist')
            else console.log('the matched directories are: ',list)
        }    
    }) 
    
});
```

The problem of this first solution is the list of matched files(in the list array) will be lower case.
The second issue is that a Set Object should get unique values, but with .toLowerCase() we are not sure anymore.

See this second solution which fix the 2 issues.

```
  const { readdir } = require("fs");
   const { join } = require('path')
             
   router.get('/displayDirectories', (req, res) => {
        const userID = req.query.id;
        const thePath = join('C:/Traning', userID)    
        
        readdir(thePath, (e,d) => {
                if(e) {
                    console.log('err parsing the directory: ', e)
                    return
                }
                else {
    
                    // set all file's name to lowercase & match them to the target 
                    const list = d.map((f,i) => {
                      if(f.toLowerCase() === userID.toLowerCase()) return f                   
                    })
                        
                    if(list.length === 0) console.log('directories does not exist')
                    else console.log('the matched directories are: ',list)
        
                }    
            }) 
   });
```